# How does suspend work in firebird?

Tags: firebird

I have a table t with one column i of type int, with a few rows.
I want to loop over it. Of course, I can write a select query for this. But I am learning procedures and wrote a procedure,

```
set term ^;
create procedure qt returns(a int) as
begin
    for select i from t into :a do
        suspend;
end^
set term ;^
```

But when I call this procedure, I only get one row back,

```
execute procedure qt;
```

I see,

```
           A 
============ 
           1
```

I think I do not understand `suspend`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stored procedures with a [`SUSPEND`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-suspend) in them are so called selectable procedures. You execute them using [`SELECT`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select):

```sql
SELECT * FROM qt
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM qt()
```

The [`EXECUTE PROCEDURE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execproc) statement is only for procedures that produce a single row result. If you use it for a selectable stored procedure, then it will only produce a single row (and exit when it hits `SUSPEND`).

In response to your inquiry about what is documented about this:

- The Interbase 6.0 Language Reference on page 177 says:

  > SUSPEND should not be used in an executable procedure.
- On page 178 it shows a table of the behavior of `SUSPEND`, `EXIT` and `END` in selectable and executable procedures (slightly modified to fit):

```
Procedure type SUSPEND                EXIT                END
Selectable     • Suspends execution   Jumps to final END  • Returns control 
                 of procedure until                         to application
                 next FETCH is issued                     • Sets SQLCODE to 100 
               • Returns output                             (end of record stream)
                 values

Executable     • Jumps to final END   Jumps to final END  • Returns values
               • Not recommended                          • Returns control 
                                                            to application
```

- For a stored procedure (shown on page 178) that can produce multiple rows, page 179 describes the differences in behavior when executed with `SELECT` and executed with `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this somewhere written in the Firebird documentation? Because I have never read this.

Comment: @ericj I would need to look that up; I don't have time to do that right now.

Comment: @ericj I have updated my answer with information from the Interbase 6 language reference.